# How can I rewrite this code using map and lambda functions?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert this list comprehension code to map and lambda code.

```
>>>list1 = [1,2,3]
>>>list2 = [10,20,30]
>>>print([m+n for m,n in zip(list1, list2)])
[11, 22, 33]
```

The code below is what I tried, but it shows TypeError

```
>>>print(list(map(lambda m,n:m+n, zip(list1, list2))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>   
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

I read that list comprehensions and labda function are interconvertible. Please point out my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` gets only one argument which is a tuple from `zip` that you need to unpack yourself:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [10,20,30]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(list1, list2)))
[11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: Thank you niemmi! Now I can see the difference thanks to you! Have a good day!